# RESTORE WINDOWS .DLL FILES

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, iso-image

I have windows 10 1511 version. About one month ago i just deleted the following files qmgr.dll and wuaueng.dll because of the windows update was taking all of my internet in name of taking just idle bandwitch. But now i wanted  that files back. But in some way i got correct wuaueng.dll file and fortunately it gets compatible with my windows and  windows update service gets started. still unable to find qmgr.dll. Because of that file BITS service is not starting. I searched on internet downloaded many qmgr.dll files but all the files are of windows xp windows 7 version. I have an ISO of windows 10 but i don`t want to reinstall it. I have heared that there are some DISM command lines that can restore missing files from an offline ISO image. On internet commandlines are given but not correctly guided how to use these line. Also there is many commandline are given but not know which one will work for me. Can anybody tells me what i need to do.

Comment: have you ever tried DISM? Does it work? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 2):

To use DISM to restore damaged/missing files, [open a cmd as admin](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) and run [this command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh824869.aspx):

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

This will download missing corrupted files. If this fails, mount the Win10 ISO/insert the WIn10 DVD ad run this command:

```
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
```

> (where D: is your Windows DVD drive or mounted Win10 ISO)

Answer (score -1):

You can also run `SFC / scannow` .

Good old XP used to have the DLLCache folder, replacing the file there and into system32 would of fixed things directly.

In W10, theres the problem of file versions. If the latest version is bad (as in incompatible with something you use), neither DSIM or SFC will fix the problem.

Comment: What makes you think SFC and DISM will not solve this problem?

Comment: Read my post more carefully. If the latest version of the DLL is not good/incompatible with what you need, neither of the commands will replace it and you will have to manually replace with an older version.

Comment: Are you saying that DISM and/or SFC won't report that those two system files are missing and/or won't attempt to restore them?  I read your answer three times, I still have a problem with it, it seems incomplete.

Comment: Let me clarify: if the system updated a .dll from version 1.00 to 1.01 and that caused something to malfunction, even if you know that specific .dll is at fault, SFC/DSIM will restore the same 1.01 version and that will not help you since for your app v.1.00 was the functional one. Therefore, you'll have to wait for a probably-fixed v 1.02 or use different means to restore v1.00. I gave this example because this type of situation is not as rare as one may think.